# JAVA Project Import Difficulty

Tags: import, program-entry-point

first off thanks for any help! I am relatively proficient at programming in languages like python, but that's not going to stop me from asking a dumb, and probably very basic question about JAVA

I am working on some satellite orbit research for graduate school, and I am using the maven compiled java project OREKIT. Information on OREKIT can be found here;https://www.orekit.org/site-orekit-9.2

I believe I have built the project correctly using the steps to import a maven project into eclipse, but I am having issues getting any of the included tutorial programs included to run.  The first errors I get are "Error: Could not find or load main class" and then followed by the name of whichever tutorial script I'm attempting to run.

MY attempt at solutions, which have not worked are as follows: First I attempted to create an entirely different java project with a main class and import the scripts I wanted to run, but I think this created more problems than it solved. Secondly, in the OREKIT project folder which was created with the maven building, there is a src folder. I right clicked and set it as the source. It contains a "main" folder with various contents but still the errors persist.

I probably am asking something extremely simple, and googlable but I haven't figured out what to google or what to do to fix my problem. If anyone has some suggestions I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Somewhere your Java app needs a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Can you post your code that is failing?

Comment: Its a relatively large project so i think it makes more sense to post the github:  https://github.com/CS-SI/Orekit

Comment: You should just need to import the project using File -> Import, then selecting Maven -> Existing Maven Projects and selecting the `pom.xml` file. It's all outlined here: https://github.com/CS-SI/Orekit/blob/develop/BUILDING.txt. Also keep in mind if you don't plan to modify their source code, you can just create your own project and include their compiled code as a dependency (their artifacts are published on Maven central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.orekit/orekit/9.2/jar).

Comment: Thanks for the help mike! Unfortunately I have already done so and still have issues. It's not that I think I need to modify their source code I just think having workable examples from their tutorial is extremely useful which is why I am asking the question!